# PHP Seclib close connection SSH

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I am using phpseclib to ssh to my server and run a python script. Here is phpseclib http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ The thing is, the python script is is made so that you can not end it once you run it. The only way to end it is to end the ssh session. Please don't ask why it is like that, as its a long story... But ctrl+c doesn't end it, nothing does except for ending the session. I know that phpseclib is supposed to automatically close the connection after the command is done executing, but technically, my command is never done executing until I end the session, so I need a function in phpseclib that will end the ssh session. I tried using exit() and die() in my php script, the script just hangs (the php script) because it thinks it is still executing the command so it doesn't get past that line of code. Terminating the php code (via browser or command line) does not stop the python script either. It would be great if someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try $ssh->setTimeout(5) or something.  eg.

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#timeout